# Open InfoWindow for each polygon google maps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon, infowindow

Hope someone can help me with this issue.
I'm trying to open an info windows on click for each polygon that my users created. 
I used the same code for a marker and works well but i couldn't make it work for each polygon.

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h2>Test</h2>'+
    '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
```

// Show Areas

```
<?php foreach ($field->result() as $f):?>

// Create an array with the coordanates of each area

var field<?=$f->id?>Coords = [
    <?php $latlng=$this->resources_data->field_latlng($f->id);?>
    <?php foreach ($latlng->result() as $point):?>
    new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$point->lat?>, <?=$point->lng?>),
    <?php endforeach;?>
];

// Create a polygon with the points of the area

var area<?=$f->id?>=new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: area<?=$f->id?>Coords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});

// Add the area to the map.

area<?=$f->id?>.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(area<?=$f->id?>,'click',function(){
    infowindow.open(map,area<?=$f->id?>)
});

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't use the same form of [InfoWindow.open](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) for a polygon as you use for a marker (there is no marker to pass in).

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)

> **open**(map?:Map|StreetViewPanorama, anchor?:MVCObject)
>
> Return Value:  None
>
> Opens this InfoWindow on the given map. Optionally, an InfoWindow can be associated with an anchor. **In the core API, the only anchor is the Marker class.** However, an anchor can be any MVCObject that exposes a LatLng position property and optionally a Point anchorPoint property for calculating the pixelOffset (see InfoWindowOptions). The anchorPoint is the offset from the anchor's position to the tip of the InfoWindow.)

You need to specifically set the place you want it to open when you call the open method (the latlng of the click is usually a good choice)  with InfoWindow.setPosition().

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_clickable_squares.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});


function initialize() {
  var geolib = google.maps.geometry.spherical;
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.738158, -117.14874),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    path: [geolib.computeOffset(new google.maps.LatLng(32.737355, -117.148719), 100, 0),
      geolib.computeOffset(new google.maps.LatLng(32.737355, -117.148719), 100, 120),
      geolib.computeOffset(new google.maps.LatLng(32.737355, -117.148719), 100, -120)
    ],
    name: "polygon1"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(polygon1, 'click', function(event) {
    var contentString = "name:" + this.name + "<br>" + event.latLng.toUrlValue(6);
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon1.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(polygon1.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  var polygon2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    path: [geolib.computeOffset(new google.maps.LatLng(32.739341, -117.148912), 90, 180),
      geolib.computeOffset(new google.maps.LatLng(32.739341, -117.148912), 90, 60),
      geolib.computeOffset(new google.maps.LatLng(32.739341, -117.148912), 90, -60)
    ],
    name: "polygon2"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(polygon2, 'click', function(event) {
    var contentString = "name:" + this.name + "<br>" + event.latLng.toUrlValue(6);
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon2.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(polygon2.getPath().getAt(i));
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function createClickablePoly(poly, html, label, point) {
  gpolys.push(poly);
  if (!point && poly.getPath && poly.getPath().getLength && (poly.getPath().getLength > 0) && poly.getPath().getAt(0)) {
    point = poly.getPath().getAt(0);
  }
  var poly_num = gpolys.length - 1;
  if (!html) {
    html = "";
  } else {
    html += "<br>";
  }
  var length = poly.Distance();
  if (length > 1000) {
    html += "length=" + poly.Distance().toFixed(3) / 1000 + " km";
  } else {
    html += "length=" + poly.Distance().toFixed(3) + " meters";
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < poly.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    html += "<br>poly[" + poly_num + "][" + i + "]=" + poly.getPath().getAt(i);
  }
  html += "<br>Area: " + poly.Area() + " sq meters";
  // html += poly.getLength().toFixed(2)+" m; "+(poly.getLength()*3.2808399).toFixed(2)+" ft; ";
  // html += (poly.getLength()*0.000621371192).toFixed(2)+" miles";
  var contentString = html;
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(event) {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    if (event) {
      point = event.latLng;
    }
    infowindow.setPosition(point);
    infowindow.open(map);
    // map.openInfoWindowHtml(point,html); 
  });
  if (!label) {
    label = "polyline #" + poly_num;
  }
  label = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gpolys[" + poly_num + "],\"click\");'>" + label + "</a>";
  // add a line to the sidebar html
  //  side_bar_html += '<input type="checkbox" id="poly'+poly_num+'" checked="checked" onclick="togglePoly('+poly_num+');">' + label + '<br />';
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<table border="1" style="height:100%; width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="200">
      <div id="report"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Make sure you aren't doing what I did, trying to pass `position` to `infowindow.open({ position: someLatLng })`. This answer shows the correct way with `infowindow.setPosition(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

function initMap() {
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             zoom: 12,
             center: {lat: 45.15492713361847, lng: 15.40557861328125}
         });

         var polygons = [{name: 'first name', coordinates:[{lat:45.15492713361847,lng:15.40557861328125},{lat:45.07933920973809,lng:15.5291748046875},{lat:45.01918507438175,lng:15.43304443359375},{lat:45.07933920973809,lng:15.3204345703125}]}];

            // foreach your polygons
            for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
                var item = polygons[i];

                var coors = item["coordinates"];
                var name = item["name"];


                var Polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    path: coors,
                    strokeColor: '#66b3ff',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 5,
                    editable: false,
                    fillColor: 'blue',
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,
                });
                Polygon.setMap(map);

                // call function to set window
                attachPolygonInfoWindow(Polygon, coors, name);
            }
        }

        function attachPolygonInfoWindow(polygon, coors, html)
        {

            polygon.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: html
            });

            polygon.infoWindow.setPosition(getHighestWindowPosition(coors));

            google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseover', function () {
                polygon.infoWindow.open(map, polygon);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseout', function () {
                polygon.infoWindow.close();
            });
        }

        // function to get highest position of polygon to show window nice on top 
        function getHighestWindowPosition(coors) {

            var lat = -5000, lng = 0, i = 0, n = coors.length;

            for (; i !== n; ++i) {
                if (coors[i].lat > lat) {
                    lat = coors[i].lat;
                    lng = coors[i].lng;
                }
            }
            return  {lat: lat, lng: lng};

        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            function loadPolygons() {
                if (gup('ProjectID') > 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "api/Polygon/GetForProject?ProjectID=" + gup('ProjectID'),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                                if (data[i].Shape.length > 0) {
                                    //alert(data[i].Shape);
                                    var myPath = JSON.parse(data[i].Shape);
                                    let latLngArray = [];
                                    for (let i = 0; i < myPath.length; i++) {
                                        latLngArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(myPath[i].lat,
                                            myPath[i].lng))
                                    }

                                    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                        paths: latLngArray,
                                        editable: false,
                                        draggable: false,
                                        clickable: true,
                                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                                        strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                                        strokeWeight: 2,
                                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                                        fillOpacity: 0.25,
                                        map: map
                                    });

                                    for (var pathidx = 0; pathidx < poly.getPath().getLength(); pathidx++) {
                                        bounds.extend(poly.getPath().getAt(pathidx));
                                    }
                                    // store the computed center as a property of the polygon for easy access
                                    poly.center = bounds.getCenter();

                                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                                    var contentString = "<div class='infoBox'><strong>Roster Date:" + data[i].RosterDateString + "</strong><br>Field Activity: " + data[i].FieldActivityDescription + "<br>View <a href='CrewRosterDetail.aspx?CrewRosterID=" + data[i].CrewRosterID + "' target='_blank'>Crew Roster</a><br><img width='150px' src='./GetProjectActivityPhoto.ashx?CrewRosterID=" + data[i].CrewRosterID + "'/></div>";

                                    // use function closure to associate the infowindow with the polygon
                                    poly.addListener('click', (function (content) {
                                    return function () {
                                        // set the content
                                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                                        // set the position
                                        infowindow.setPosition(this.center);
                                        // open it
                                        infowindow.open(map);
                                    }
                                    })(contentString));

                                    map.setZoom(18);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            alert(msg.ExceptionMessage);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please save the Project and some project activities before attempting to display polygons!");
                }
            }
```