# Angular google map, polygones and informations inside them

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I m actually developping an application using Google Maps v3 and http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps.

Actually, I have to display some polygons (and it works well) but I want to display information inside this, like how many beer bars are present here, or how many restaurant ect...

In fact, I only need to display something, but I dont know how. I know how to make it with marker, but not with polygones and polylines...

Can you help me ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: How do you want to display the information inside the polygon? A label, info window?

Comment: Might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017915/open-infowindow-for-each-polygon-google-maps-v3  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930567/put-label-on-google-maps-polygon-received-by-geojson-data